# Which users have most questions with 0 or less upvote with no accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

For given Stack Exchange (like Law), how can I see  list of all users, ordered by number of their questions, that have

1. have 0 or less upvote?
2. no accepted answer?

What if I want

3. no answer at all, rather than just accepted answer?

I never study programming or computer science! I don't know how program this.

Comment: You can go [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and compose a query to do it.

Comment: Something like this: https://data.stackexchange.com/law/query/1210914 ?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Only if you happen to be competent in writing a particular type of code. I don't think the number of downvotes on this question is fair.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I would agree. I didn't downvote, but I'm also not good enough at writing SEDE queries to do it myself (at least not in any reasonable amount of time). I figured pointing them in the right direction would be better than nothing.

Comment: @Randal'Thor With the voting trends I've seen and experienced here with SEDE questions I suspect at times that people forget this is actually the place you are supposed to ask those.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I suspect too many people forget that not everyone on the SE network is a programmer. They think this is just so easy that it shouldn't even be a question.

Comment: I think the you and @Rubiksmoose may generalise a bit too much, Rand. People can also downvote because of the "not useful" criterion given in the tooltip; I know that's the reason _I_ picked, and certainly not proficiency in whatever. I don't see how this question improves Meta.SE's content, though of course that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: I have no idea what's causing the downvoting spree here. Didn't we use to have a be nice policy, especially for new users? Welcome to Stack Exchange Aster! /s

Comment: @Jenayah  "I don't see how this question improves Meta.SE's content" -> because others may have the same question.

Comment: @Jenayah And it would be a real example usage of queries.

Comment: @Frank meh-ish argument. Every on-topic question could be wondered about by other people..  doesn't mean none of them should be downvoted. I have my opinion on this question, you have yours, we disagree, it's fine. No need for us to try and convince the other further :) just an obligatory comment though, about the Be Nice policy, downvotes aren't rude... They never were, they're not about the people, etc... (I'm sure it's a chorus you've already heard, here again no need to discuss that further)

Comment: @rene Why not maken an answer out of it?

Comment: @SQB well, I find the specs a tad unclear. I only realized once I started out. Also I didn't have time to add the last requirement in so I left it at a comment, waiting for confirmation that my attempt is on the right track

Comment: @rene yes thanks! can you add users' reputation as a column? i want see a column of users' reputation. i want upload people with less reputation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/law/query/1210914) that implements your first two requirements.

Promise you don't use this query to go on a serial upvote spree.

The query basically is a left outer join between post and votes where rows with a votetypeid = 2 do not need to be present.

The rest is shaping and reducing noise.

```sql
select owneruserid [User Link]
     , count(distinct p.id) [# Q no upmod]
     , min(u.reputation) [reputation]
from posts p
left outer join votes up on up.postid = p.id and votetypeid = 2 -- upmod
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where p.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and up.id is null -- no upvotes
and acceptedanswerid is null -- no accepted answer
group by  owneruserid 
order by count(*) desc
```

When run today on Law this is what the result looks like:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).